# Water's around, but not too much,

Tags: riddle

> Water's around, but not too much,
>
> Maybe you like it,
>
> But should not touch.

**What is it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is a

> Cactus.
>
>  In a desert there is barely any water, but there is enough for plants like a cactus to survive.
>
>  They are pleasant to look at, but you don't want to touch one or you will get pricked by its spines.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Steam

As

> Steam is the gaseous form of water and a small mass of it can occupy a relatively large volume at standard pressure. This would satisfy the condition of a small amount of water and it being 'around'. Steam is hot and can burn so you shouldn't touch it however many people like to look at steam from a distance as it can be visually pleasing

Comment: It wasn't the one I was thinking about, but nice job

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, assuming that "it" is the same as in "... like it", is

> alcohol. Without proper hydration, drinking is, as we all know, not recommended.

However, any analogous

> diuretic

would serve this purpose, such as

> salt.